# Is the elementwise product of a positive semidefinite matrix and a negative semidefinite matrix negative semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A = (a_{ij})$ is positve semidefinite and $B = (b_{ij})$ is negative semidefinite, then is $C = (a_{ij}b_{ij})$ (elementwise product) negative semidefinite?

What I'm concerned is a weaker conclusion: is $\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}b_{ij} \leq 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's a limiting case of [Schur product theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem) (and the theorem itself is just an easy consequence of the fact that the Hadamard product of two matrices is just a submatrix of their Kronecker product).

Since $A\circ B$ is negative semidefinite, $\mathbf1^T(A\circ B)\mathbf1\le0$.

Comment: As I understand it, Shur product theorem concerns two positive semidefinite matrices. Can you explain to me how it can be used in this situation, where one of the matrices is negative semidefinite? Thank you

Comment: @jdizzle Consider $-B$ instead of $B$.